# why there is difference in custom fonts of ios and android

Tags: android, fonts

i'm using same font.ttf in ios and android. It is looking good in ios but in android, it seems slightly bold. same as fontlight.ttf looking good in ios but in android it is looking like regular. what is the problem with? is it of resolution or i'm missing something.

Comment: I am not sure but it could be due to different density on devices.